# How to implement 2 timers in linux

Tags: c, linux, timer

I m trying to set the flag variable on(working with raspbery pi. I need pin on) for 500 useconds(micro seconds) and flag off for 300 useconds continuously(infinitely until I stop it). I thought of implementing it using 2 timers.

Now In this program i have written for 5 seconds and 3 seconds.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct sigaction sa;
struct itimerval timer1,timer2;
 int count=1;
void timer_handler (int signum)
{
 if(count++%2==1)
    printf("High\n"); //flag=1
 else  
    printf("Low\n");   //flag=0
}

 int main ()
{


 /* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM. */
 memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
 sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
 sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
 sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);


 int i=0;
 while(1){
    scanf(" %d",&i);
    if(i==1){  // I m starting 2 timers here 
 timer1.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
 timer1.it_value.tv_usec = 1;
 timer1.it_interval.tv_sec = 8; //5+3
 timer1.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

 timer2.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
 timer2.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
 timer2.it_interval.tv_sec = 8;
 timer2.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
 setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer1, NULL);
  setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer2, NULL);
 }
 else if(i==2)  // I m stopping here 
 {
    timer1.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
 timer1.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
 timer1.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
 timer1.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

 timer2.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
 timer2.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
 timer2.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
 timer2.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
 setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer1, NULL);   // 1st timer on
  setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer2, NULL);  //2nd timer on 

 }
}
}
```

This is code I have written. 
what actually happening is the second timer is running and first timer is not running. I think its overwritten.

Ps. I dont want to use sleep function as it takes more time. I m using timers as the resolution is microsecond.

1.How do I do this using two timers? 
2.Is there any better method to do this task?

Comment: printf isn't async safe, so you may get weird behaviour having it in a signal handler.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Just for debugging purposes. How do I do it using 2 timers ?

Comment: the purpose doesn't matter, this *will* cause weird behavior. A signal-handler should do as little as possible, a good thing is to only set a `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag.

Comment: As for your question, there **is** only **one** `ITIMER_REAL`. You'll have to virtualize it yourself with some dispatching code.

Comment: @FelixPalmen how to virtualize using dispatching code ?

Comment: You'll have to come up with your own idea I guess. Somehow, you need a function calculating which of your virtual timers should expire next and update `ITIMER_REAL` with `setitimer()` accordingly.

Comment: A simple and reliable approach is to have a periodic `ITIMER_REAL` with a small period (depending on your needs, e.g. 100ms) and have your virtual timers be multiples of this. After each `SIGALRM`, decrement your virtual timers.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `ITIMER_REAL`, so you must create virtual timers yourself. A simple and reliable possibility if you don't need microsecond precision, is to use a periodic timer with a small interval and implement your virtual timers on top of that (so every "*tick*" from your periodic timer will decrement your virtual timers).

Following an example how you could implement it:

#### vtimer.h

```
#ifndef VTIMER_H
#define VTIMER_H

typedef void (vtimer_timeout)(void *arg);

typedef struct vtimer
{
    int msec;
    int periodic;
    int current;
    vtimer_timeout *timeout;
} vtimer;

#define vtimer_init(m, p, cb) { \
    .msec=(m), .periodic=(p), .current=0, .timeout=cb}

void vtimer_start(vtimer *self, void *timeoutArg);
void vtimer_stop(vtimer *self);

// call this periodically, e.g. after each interrupted library call:
void vtimer_dispatch();

#endif
```

#### vtimer.c

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200101L

#include "vtimer.h"

#include <stddef.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define NUM_TIMERS 8

static vtimer *timers[NUM_TIMERS] = {0};
static void *timoutArgs[NUM_TIMERS] = {0};

static size_t ntimers = 0;

static volatile sig_atomic_t ticks = 0;

static void tickhandler(int signum)
{
    (void)signum;
    ++ticks;
}

static struct sigaction timerAction = {.sa_handler = tickhandler};
static struct sigaction defaultAction;
static struct itimerval tickTimerval = {{0, 1000}, {0, 1000}};
static struct itimerval disableTimerval = {{0,0},{0,0}};

void vtimer_start(vtimer *self, void *timeoutArg)
{
    int found = 0;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NUM_TIMERS; ++idx)
    {
        if (timers[idx] == self)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        if (ntimers == NUM_TIMERS) return; // or maybe return error
        if (!ntimers++)
        {
            // only start the "ticking" timer when necessary
            sigaction(SIGALRM, &timerAction, &defaultAction);
            setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tickTimerval, 0);
        }
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NUM_TIMERS; ++idx)
        {
            if (!timers[idx])
            {
                timers[idx] = self;
                timoutArgs[idx] = timeoutArg;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    self->current = self->msec;
}

void vtimer_stop(vtimer *self)
{
    int found = 0;
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NUM_TIMERS; ++idx)
    {
        if (timers[idx] == self)
        {
            timers[idx] = 0;
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found && !--ntimers)
    {
        // no virtual timers running -> stop ticking timer
        setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &disableTimerval, 0);
        sigaction(SIGALRM, &defaultAction, 0);
    }
}

void vtimer_dispatch(void)
{
    while (ticks)
    {
        --ticks;
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NUM_TIMERS; ++idx)
        {
            if (timers[idx])
            {
                if (!--(timers[idx]->current))
                {
                    timers[idx]->timeout(timoutArgs[idx]);
                    if (timers[idx]->periodic)
                    {
                        timers[idx]->current = timers[idx]->msec;
                    }
                    else vtimer_stop(timers[idx]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example program using this:

```
#include "vtimer.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void timer1_timeout(void *arg)
{
    (void) arg;
    puts("timer 1");
}

static void timer2_timeout(void *arg)
{
    (void) arg;
    puts("timer 2");
}

int main(void)
{
    vtimer timer1 = vtimer_init(5000, 1, timer1_timeout);
    vtimer timer2 = vtimer_init(8000, 1, timer2_timeout);

    vtimer_start(&timer1, 0);
    vtimer_start(&timer2, 0);

    for (;;)
    {
        errno = 0;
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF && errno != EINTR) break;
        if (c == 'q') break;
        vtimer_dispatch();
    }

    vtimer_stop(&timer2);
    vtimer_stop(&timer1);
    return 0;
}
```

There are a lot of design decisions on the way (e.g. how frequent your ticks should be (here 1ms), having a fixed number of virtual timers vs a dynamic one, using pointers as "timer handles" or maybe integers, and so on), so think about what you need and try to write your own.